# Loop through array for each value from another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I loop through this array:

```
const counts = [
  "900,google.com",
  "60,mail.yahoo.com",
  "10,mobile.sports.yahoo.com",
  "40,sports.yahoo.com",
  "300,yahoo.com",
  "10,stackoverflow.com",
  "20,overflow.com",
  "5,com.com",
  "2,en.wikipedia.org",
  "1,m.wikipedia.org",
  "1,mobile.sports",
  "1,google.co.uk",
];
```

taking each value from this array?

```
const uniqueDomains = [
  'google.com',
  'com',
  'mail.yahoo.com',
  'yahoo.com',
  'mobile.sports.yahoo.com',
  'sports.yahoo.com',
  'stackoverflow.com',
  'overflow.com',
  'com.com',
  'en.wikipedia.org',
  'wikipedia.org',
  'org',
  'm.wikipedia.org',
  'mobile.sports',
  'sports',
  'google.co.uk',
  'co.uk',
  'uk'
]
```

I need to find out if string from counts array includes string from uniqueDomains array.
Then push it to the empty object as a key value pairs, where value
is going to be the number in the beginning of the each string from counts array.

I tried this code but it give me wrong result in my object's values(since I am looping twice)
I need kind of avoid looping twice, but I am not sure how.

Example com is mentioned 8 time in counts array, which means result should be this {com: 1345}

Here is my code:

```
const finalObject = {}
uniqueDomains.forEach((dom) => {
  counts.forEach((cnt) => {
    if (cnt.includes(dom)) {
      const num = parseInt(cnt);
      sumArr.push(num);
      const res = sumArr.reduce((acc, cur) => {
        return acc + cur;
      });
      finalObject[dom] = res;
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: make a copy of `counts` array by splitting using `,`, so it looks like `[ ["900" , "google.com"] ]`, then you can loop over `uniqueDomains` and use `Array.find`

Comment: ok but into find method I need to the another string from the second array which means that I have to loop again.

Comment: Can you show the full output you're expecting. ie why does `com` being mentioned 8 times give it the value `1345`?

Comment: @Sonny49 yeah, that was on top of my head. you definitely need to improve the time complexity for that

Comment: In count array com has been mentioned 8 times, if you use includes method.

Comment: 8 times getting integer of that string makes 1345

Comment: I have also created a separate object from counts array where domain is on the left side and number on the right but now I realise that it is redundant

Comment: Sorry, I should have say that value has to be sum of the integers but this is not a main problem. First I need to iterate through it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theres not really any avoiding looping twice (at least), but you can certainly make your code a bit easieer by first turning the count array into an array of `val` & `domain` separately.

```
const countIdx = counts.map(x => {
   const [val,domain] = x.split(",");
   return {val:parseInt(val,10), domain}
});
```

Then its just a case of looping the `uniqueDomain` array and finding all the `domaion` which match and summing up the `val`

```
const result = uniqueDomains.reduce( (res, d) => {
    const count = countIdx.filter(x => x.domain.includes(d)).reduce( (acc,x) => acc + x.val,0);
    return {...res, [d]:count}
},{});
```

Live example follows:

```js
const counts = [
  "900,google.com",
  "60,mail.yahoo.com",
  "10,mobile.sports.yahoo.com",
  "40,sports.yahoo.com",
  "300,yahoo.com",
  "10,stackoverflow.com",
  "20,overflow.com",
  "5,com.com",
  "2,en.wikipedia.org",
  "1,m.wikipedia.org",
  "1,mobile.sports",
  "1,google.co.uk",
];

const uniqueDomains = [
  'google.com',
  'com',
  'mail.yahoo.com',
  'yahoo.com',
  'mobile.sports.yahoo.com',
  'sports.yahoo.com',
  'stackoverflow.com',
  'overflow.com',
  'com.com',
  'en.wikipedia.org',
  'wikipedia.org',
  'org',
  'm.wikipedia.org',
  'mobile.sports',
  'sports',
  'google.co.uk',
  'co.uk',
  'uk'
]

const countIdx = counts.map(x => {
   const [val,domain] = x.split(",");
   return {val:parseInt(val,10), domain}
});

const result = uniqueDomains.reduce( (res, d) => {
    const count = countIdx.filter(x => x.domain.includes(d)).reduce( (acc,x) => acc + x.val,0);
    return {...res, [d]:count}
},{});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like:

```js
let finalObject = {}
uniqueDomains.forEach((dom) => {
  finalObject[dom] = 0;
  counts.forEach((cnt) => {
    if (cnt.includes(dom)) {
      finalObject[dom] += parseInt(cnt);
    }
  });
});
```